# Lidando com altura em percentual [HTML/CSS]

Tags: html, css, front-end

boa noite. Estou aprendendo tecnologia para programação front-end e me deparei com um programa ao definir o tamanho da pagina em percentual. Eu tenho uma DIV e dentro dessas DIV eu tenho mais duas, ficando assim:

```
<div class="pai">
    <div class="Filho-1">
    </div>
    <div class="filho-2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Quando eu tento definir uma margem superior para o filho 1 em percentual, essa margem é aplicada ao pai, mas e queria que o filho 1 ficasse com uma margem dentro da div pai.

Vou mandar o HTML e o CSS no pastebin e vou anexar o print da tela.

HTML: https://pastebin.com/LuaG5BQm
CSS: https://pastebin.com/smzcGzJn

[image: Com a margem top na DIV filho]

[image: Sem a margem na Div filho]

Queria que esse quadrado preto tivesse uma margem em relação a divisão verde.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> As margens superior e inferior dos blocos às vezes são combinadas(colapsadas/reduzidas) para uma única margem cujo o tamanho é a maior das margens (se os elementos tiverem a mesma margem, uma delas não será somada), combinado a ele, um comportamento conhecido como margin collapsing.

Leia mais sobre margin collapsing [aqui.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/margin_collapsing)

Para resolver seu caso específico, você deve adicionar a propriedade `overflow:auto` à classe da div conteudo.msg.

Desta forma:

**CSS**

```
.conteudo-msg{
    background-color: #169C79;
    height: 35%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Você pode compreender melhor a propriedade **overflow** [nesse artigo da w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp).

Comment: Cara, perfeito! Muitíssimo obrigado.